# WHMCS add on module Product::pricing() error logged

Tags: whmcs

I've taken over a company that is currently running WHMCS 8.4.1 and has a custom built add-on module.
I want to upgrade WHMCS to 8.5.1 so I set up a dev environment and installed the add-on files to it.
As soon as I try to open the add-on I get the following error:

Whoops\Exception\ErrorException: Declaration of ProductExtended\Core\Models\WHMCS\Product::pricing() must be compatible with WHMCS\Product\Product::pricing($currency = ): WHMCS\Product\Pricing in /Users/steph/Sites/localhost/whmcs/modules/addons/ProductExtended/Core/Models/WHMCS/Product.php:22

Stack trace:
#0 /Users/steph/Sites/localhost/whmcs/vendor/whmcs/whmcs-foundation/lib/Utility/Error/Run.php(0): WHMCS\Utility\Error\Run->handleError(64, 'Declaration of ...', '/Users/steph/Si...', 22)
#1 [internal function]: WHMCS\Utility\Error\Run->handleShutdown()
#2 {main}

I've never done any WHMCS coding before, but based on the error I would assume that there have been changes in the core way that

```
pricing()
```

is coded.

All the main files are encrypted so impossible to look at those to see what differs to version 8.4.1

Does anyone have any suggestions on where I might find some resources to help resolve this, and likely other changes that could affect the add-on?

I have looked at the 8.5.1 Realease Notes, Changelog and What's New documents, but found nothing specifically related to code changes.

Answer (score 0):

Check to see whether /Users/steph/Sites/localhost/whmcs/modules/addons/ProductExtended/Core/Models/WHMCS/Product.php is coded by ioncube (the default WHMCS PHP encoder)

Answer (score 0):

If you do not have access to the source code of the module, there's nothing *you* can do to fix the issue. You would need to contact the developer to have the module updated to support the version of WHMCS that you need.

If the module code is encoded, there's no way (at least legally) that you can decode it.